# SASS: syntax errors when using shorthand syntax

Tags: sass

My scss file is this:

```
@import "compass/typography/lists/bullets";
.view-content ul
  +no-bullets
```

This gives me an error on the page:

> Syntax error: Invalid css after "  +no-bullets": expected "{", was ""

However, when the rule looks like this:

```
.view-content ul {
  @include no-bullets;
}
```

then it's OK and bullets are gone.

But I like the shorthand notation, how to enable using it?

Comment: I didn't find any references in the SASS references to the shorthand you want to use. Can you tell me where you found it?

Comment: http://www.zivtech.com/blog/css-suckers-introduction-sass-compass - look for sentence "Or you can use the shorthand syntax"

Comment: You're right, I found [the related documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html). I tried [the following](https://gist.github.com/3146005) and it works. I didn't try with compass, yet. What is your SASS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, I found [the related documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html).

I tried [the following](https://gist.github.com/3146005) and it works.

Then, I tried your and it didn't work until I remove the trailing `;` on the `import` instruction.

```
@import "compass/typography/lists/bullets"

.view-content ul
  +no-bullets
```

The following works with Compass 0.12.2. Try removing the trailing `;` on the `import` instruction.

Comment: I am a little confused, because now, after building the scss file with many more rules, I stopped receiving this error at all, no matter whether there is ";" after import or not. But I will observe this, the must be some rule to this.